# Opening Ajax Response(pdf) in new window browser. Ok with Firefox bur error in chrome (Django+Javascript)

Tags: jquery, django, reportlab

Trying to show reportlab generated pdf in Browser. In firefox it is showing fine. But chrome/IE not showing the pdf. What is the easiest way to generate very basic pdf and show in browser so that i could be printed easily by printer.

Django View(PDF generation):

```
def print_users(request,*args,**kwargs):
        # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate PDF headers.
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf; charset=utf-8')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="MyUsers.pdf";charset=utf-8'
        buffer = BytesIO()
        report = MyPrint(buffer, 'Letter')
        pdf = report.print_users()
        response.write(pdf)
        return response**
```

Ajax Call(Show pdf):

```
  $.ajax({
url: "/order/print/users/",
type: "post",
//data: { "category": myObject }
}).done(function (result) {
    window.open("data:application/pdf," + encodeURIComponent(result));
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
// needs to implement if it fails
});
```

Response from server -->
  console.log(result)-->

```
%PDF-1.4
%���� ReportLab Generated PDF document http://www.reportlab.com
1 0 obj
<<
/F1 2 0 R
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/BaseFont /Helvetica /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /Name /F1 /Subtype /Type1 /Type /Font
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/Contents 7 0 R /MediaBox [ 0 0 612 792 ] /Parent 6 0 R /Resources <<
/Font 1 0 R /ProcSet [ /PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI ]
>> /Rotate 0 /Trans <<

>> 
  /Type /Page
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<<
/Outlines 8 0 R /PageMode /UseNone /Pages 6 0 R /Type /Catalog
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/Author (\(anonymous\)) /CreationDate (D:20170826165648-06'00') /Creator (\(unspecified\)) /Keywords () /ModDate (D:20170826165648-06'00') /Producer (ReportLab PDF Library - www.reportlab.com) 
  /Subject (\(unspecified\)) /Title (\(anonymous\)) /Trapped /False
>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<<
/Count 1 /Kids [ 3 0 R ] /Type /Pages
>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<<
/Filter [ /ASCII85Decode /FlateDecode ] /Length 201
>>
stream
Gat%YbmM<A&;9LtME.\mAj^;*W1^%.Pi`-akc`QFS%cYl."WLn1@-':R;W@o7H)u:fGgoQ"B$oW-sB%n)@%K.K&4U[K1%1!ZR:CWQ%EfD+`Xu>;.Q>uOYJq?Y0!e9mk[3#\3$>/@2bNPa?R#F2WCj/^6.,Qf0ujK$W?H[[;rbMmg.h3OkihD]n_K3:m-t`5/\*qE_K@~>endstream
endobj
8 0 obj
<<
/Count 0 /Type /Outlines
>>
endobj
xref
0 9
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000073 00000 n 
0000000104 00000 n 
0000000211 00000 n 
0000000404 00000 n 
0000000488 00000 n 
0000000771 00000 n 
0000000830 00000 n 
0000001121 00000 n 
trailer
<<
/ID 
[<fb3a83ec0486d40485c0b5b76feed691><fb3a83ec0486d40485c0b5b76feed691>]
% ReportLab generated PDF document -- digest (http://www.reportlab.com)

/Info 5 0 R
/Root 4 0 R
/Size 9
>>
startxref
1167
%%EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
window.open("data:application/IMG," + escape(result));
```